# AWS MWAA Airflow is failing for only some tasks as "Could not read remote logs from log_group"

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, mwaa

I have a big Airflow dag in AWS which is failing only for some tasks, other tasks are getting completed and showing logs.

```
*** Reading remote log from Cloudwatch log_group: airflow-a****l-Task log_stream: p****s_em**_br***s/e*******************p/2023-10-27T04_30_00+00_00/2.log.
Could not read remote logs from log_group: airflow-a****l-Task log_stream: p****s_em**_br***s/e*******************p/2023-10-27T04_30_00+00_00/2.log.
```

It was working fine till yesterday. And no changes were made for this to occur.